# Display all images from a directory on a Jekyll powered website

Tags: ruby, image, web, jekyll, liquid

It doesn't necessarily have to be something Jekyll uses.

Basically I'm creating a gallery that will use lightbox. I want to load all the images from a directory (_site\images\gallery) for the lightbox to display and their thumbnails (to be determined and created).

What would be the best way to go about this? I already have lightbox set up and tested (no thumbnails).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Jekyll doesn't have a way to "list the contents of a folder".

You can do a very approximate thing by using the yaml front though.

In the "gallery page", include a section with the file names of the images:

```
---
images:
  - a.jpg
  - b.jpg
  - c.jpg
<other properties, like title, etc>
---
```

Then, when you want to list your images, produce the links with a loop. I'm not familiar with lighbox's syntax for images, but it will probably look like similar to this:

```
<ul class="something">
{% for image in page.images %}
  <li class="something">
    <a rel="something" class="something" href="/path/to/images/dir/{{ image }}" />
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

(I have put "something" on every place when I'm not sure about something. It might be possible that you will have to remove some "somethings" completely. You will have to modify `/path/to/images/dir/` to where your images are)

Once the html is changed to work with lightbox, the only thing you have to do to add a new image is: a) putting it in the images directory and b) Edit the gallery page, and introduce the new image name in the list.

It's not as convenient as having the list "automatically generated", but it's very close.

Answer (score 3):

Listing the jpg files in the current directory in Jekyll can be done like this:

```
{% for file in site.static_files %}
  {% assign pageurl = page.url | replace: 'index.html', '' %}
  {% if file.path contains pageurl %}
    {% if file.extname == '.jpg' or file.extname == '.jpeg' or file.extname == '.JPG' or file.extname == '.JPEG' %}
    <img src="{{ file.path }}" />
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

More about this solution can be found here: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/. I have created a lightbox extension for Jekyll that is listed on my page [Jekyll without plugins](http://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/lightbox/). Check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/simoarpe/azores-image-gallery

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author.

I've tried some of the projects already available on Github but most of them are discontinued or partially working and in the end, I decided to implement something on my own starting from the good bits found around.
The result is [Azores Image Gallery](https://github.com/simoarpe/azores-image-gallery).
For a more detailed explanation check the [README file](https://github.com/simoarpe/azores-image-gallery/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

I love Jekyll plugins.

Try one of these: [Jekyll Gallery](https://github.com/m0tive/jekyll-gallery), [Jekyll Gallery Generator](https://github.com/ggreer/jekyll-gallery-generator), or [Folder Gallery](https://github.com/krig/jekyll-plugins#foldergalleryrb).

Check out the Ruby file for each plugin and modify the image tag generated to include the class for lightbox. That should do the trick. Don't forget to include the lightbox css file in your default template page.